# is it possible assign different return type for method

Tags: java, generics

My idea is that there is a validator interface, which has method `getRealValue()`. The return value depends on field, it could be `String`, `Integer` or `Long` values.

My chances are:

1. I can do assign return type as `Object` and use casting every time after I called this method. (`RuntimeError` if wrong casting happened).
2. I can use generic an pass return type to validator when instantiate it (and I still have to use casting but inside method `getRealValue` and only once). Still `RuntimeError` if I will forget to pass return type or pass wrong type.

If there is a way I  can store return type inside validator and use it?

Comment: Your desire to do this generally indicates a deeper design problem.

Comment: It is common problem to validate data which comes from user. Any better design can be used? My solution is straightforward and easy to use in case if it is python. But i am closed with java.

Answer (score 10):

For your 1st point, there is no way around getting a `ClassCastException` at runtime in case of an inappropriate cast.

In your second case you won't need to cast, see example here:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public T getValue(); 
}
```

... then somewhere else:

```
public class Blah<T> implements Foo<T> {
    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        // TODO write the code
        // note that because of type erasure you won't know what type T is here
        return null;
    }
}
```

... then, somewhere else:

```
Blah blah1 = new Blah<String>();
String s = blah1.getValue();
Blah blah2 = new Blah<Long>();
// etc.
```

Finally, here's some **literature** for you:

- [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) in Java
- [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in Java (has a section on casting)

Comment: I read and generic and inheritance before. I get use to python style. Xmmm found interesting method in class object as cast. Will look forward on it.

Comment: Helpful and thorough +1 :)